# How do I send arduino a firmata command to turn on a pin

Tags: arduino, firmata

I'm trying to implement the firmata protocol and having a bit of a difficult time deciphering the spec for writing digital pins:

I have noted the following parts of the [spec of Firmata 2.3](http://firmata.org/wiki/V2.3ProtocolDetails)

```
* type                command  channel    first byte            second byte 
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
* digital I/O message   0x90   port       LSB(bits 0-6)         MSB(bits 7-13)
```

and

```
/* two byte digital data format, second nibble of byte 0 gives the port number (e.g. 0x92 is the third port, port 2)
 * 0  digital data, 0x90-0x9F, (MIDI NoteOn, but different data format)
 * 1  digital pins 0-6 bitmask
 * 2  digital pin 7 bitmask 
 */
```

I'm having some difficulty interpreting the spec.  I've looked at other implementations, but haven't been able to see the relationship between the spec and implementation.

So let's say I am wanting to turn on the Arduino LED (pin 13), I know it will be on the second port, port 1, so the first byte will be `#{91}`.

I'm getting confused about the bitmask for the second two bytes though.  I know what a bitmask is, so I want to enable the right bit for the pin.

- Why is the bitmask so large for the digital pins?  I'm familiar with using bitmasks on the digital outputs of PLCs, which seems much different (one pin, one bit)
- My thought is that pin 13 would be the 7th pin on port 1.  Since I don't care about the other pins, I would mark the pin in the 2nd byte #{40} and I don't need any pins set for the third byte #{00}?

I don't think my interpretation of the bitmasks is correct, and it's probably where my error is

Am I on the right track for this?  Is this the right command for setting a pin high or low?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some `strace` debugging with the firmata test application, I discovered the simple command to turn on Pin 13 was:

```
#{912000}
```

and to turn it off:

```
#{910000}
```